# Formatting Text in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, text, richtextbox

I need to format the font of a `RichTextBox` - but only some lines.
I am writing an update Tool at the moment and it has an implemented Changelog.

What I know that I have to implement a `RichTextBox` and get rid of the old textbox. Now I need to do it like this,

> **2.5.5302.13819 vom 08.07.2014**
>
> - Unterstützung von Peer 2 Peer Netzwerken mit Arbeitsgruppe im Lizensierungsmodell
>
> **2.5.5297.26083 vom 03.07.2014**
>
> - Mehrmalige bzw. doppelte Aktualisierung der Beleg- und Auftragssteuerung unterbunden
> - diverse Kleinigkeiten

My idea is to set each line as bold (or to have a larger font size) after a `\n` but how do I format them to as such (I haven't written any code yet)?

Comment: You can only ever format a piece of your text when it is __selected__. Set SelectionStart and SelectionLength and then the formats. (SelectionBullet & SelectionFont.Bold)

Comment: That means that the hard part will bee to do those selections.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it:

```
using (Font boldFont = new Font(txtRelease.Font, FontStyle.Bold)) {
  foreach (string sLine in txtRelease.Lines) {
    if (sLine.Length > 0) {
      if (char.IsNumber(sLine[0]) && sLine.Contains("vom")) {
        txtRelease.SelectionStart = txtRelease.Text.IndexOf(sLine);
        txtRelease.SelectionLength = sLine.Length;
        txtRelease.SelectionFont = boldFont;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I replaced your image with an updated code block of your code.  You should dispose of your fonts, so I put it in a using block.  I could not duplicate the first line bug, it bolded the first line in my list.  If you don't like the edit, feel free to roll it back to the original version.

Comment: It works fine now..For..Some reason. Strange behaviour. But thanks for the help mate ;)